# Linux kernel. How to send/receive unaddressed frame at Link Layer

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

I am currently building an open source radio network communication subsystem.
I have a prototype that works in two ecosystems (MBED-OS or Raspberry Pico SDK),
which can work with the transceiver built into the NRF52 series microcontrollers or any
transceiver connected via the SPI link (e.g. RF22/23B).
The system is somewhat similar to the existing ones,
but it is much simpler and does not impose any special requirements on the functions of transceiver.
It can work with any radio that sends/receives frames with some consistency check (CRC or similar).
I would like to transfer a working prototype to the Linux/WiFi platform.
It is not too difficult, but I have a problem with accessing the network stack at a sufficiently low level.
I need the ability to send/receive a packet (frame) with a minimum header size (preferably empty:).
To ensure connectivity between nodes, I configured an "Ad-Hoc" wlan (I do not need an access point because I have implemented my own network switches).
I have built a loadable kernel module that could send/receive frames from applications via SysFS and transfer it to network.

And now the main problem.

How to send a simple frame from the kernel module using only the lowest layer of the stack (Link Layer).
Most of the examples using the 'dev_queue_xmit' function build higher layer (IP/Ethernet) packets appending appropriate headers.
I don't know if it is possible to send simple unaddressed packets (into the air)?
And whether these packets will be received and forwarded for processing when I register my own handler using 'dev_add_pack'

I am asking for advice on how to approach such a problem.
The kernel module and the lowest layer of the network are needed because I need timestamps of sent/received frames and I would not like to get disturbed (millisecond) delays.

Regards,
TIA

Comment: If you are using IEEE 802.11 (Wi-Fi) then you must have 802.11 frames, which include MAC addressing. The 802.11 hardware requires that. The same thing holds for protocols like IEEE 802.3 (ethernet).

Answer (score 0):

According to the 802.11 standard, a frame can contain from 1 to 4 addresses depending on the frame type. For example, the CTS frame has only one address field and the 'data' type frames can have as many as 4.